# Upload files with ajax and Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I've problem with upload file from form to Symfony2 controller by ajax.

This is my form by client side:

```
var uploadFile = function() {
var content = "<form id='uploadFile' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='' method='post'>" +
        "<input id='file' type='file'/>" +
        "</form>";
$("#upload-dialog").html(content);
$("#upload-dialog").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    title: 'Dodaj załączniki do umowy',
    height: 300,
    width: 450,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Wyślij',
            click: function() {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
                $.ajax({
                   url: Routing.generate('employees_upload_attachment'),
                   data: formData,
                   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                   processData: false,
                   contentType: false,
                   success: function() {
                   },
                   error: function() {

                   }
                });
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

};

and this is my controller

```
    public function uploadAttachmentAction(Request $request) {
    $fileBag = $request->files;
    var_dump($fileBag);
}
```

When I try to show uploaded file I get an empty FileBag object:

> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag)#12 (1) {
>   ["parameters":protected]=>   array(0) {   } }

What could be wrong?

EDIT:
I solved it.I added to jquery ajax parameters

> cache: false, type: 'POST'

and everything is ok :)

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `document.getElementById('file').files[0]`?

Comment: Yes, It's looks good.

Comment: I solved this problem. I added to ajax paramaters: cache: false and type: 'POST'. Now everything is ok :)

Comment: I'm trying something similar, but with the validate the form, to ensure integrity in my data, can help me? [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33283234/how-upload-file-in-ajax-jquery-with-symfony2)

Comment: @math Please answer your own question, or delete it. It's still showing up in the "unanswered" section. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Adding  ajax paramaters:

```
cache: false,
type: 'POST'
```

Solved problem.

*Note: Answer is based on comment not mine because it is showing up in the "unanswered" section.*