# How to upload file using ajax/jQuery with Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

Could anyone help me?

I'm trying to write a script that when the user clicks an image, that this triggers an image in the database to be updated.

For this I wrote the code which temporarily makes the Caller Line of the method in the controller, but when I send the form it is not validated because of Cross-Site-Request-Forgery.

```
$("#upload_picture").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#bundle_user_file").trigger('click');
});

$("#bundle_user_file").change(function () {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('.active-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        ajax_formData()
    }
});
```

This is my Caller Line ajax, is do the treatment in the form with the FormData to post, caught the routes and the token. He calls route, but not sure if the image is going or not, even with the Inspector firefox.

```
function ajax_formData() {
     var at = $("form[name=bundle_user]");
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('file', $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0]);
     var url = at.attr('action') + '?_token=' + $("#bundle_user__token").val();
     $.ajax({
         type: "PUT",
         url: url,
         data: formData,
         success: function (data) {
             alert("success: " + data.message);
         },
         fail: function (data) {
             alert("error: " + data.message);
         },
         cache: false,
         contentType: false,
         processData: false,
         xhr: function () {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
             var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
             if (myXhr.upload) { // Avalia se tem suporte a         propriedade upload
                 myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function ()               {
                 /* faz alguma coisa durante o progresso do upload */
             }, false);
         }
         return myXhr;
     }
 });
```

}

This is the method in controlodor it with a common call with the click the button to submit change my image. But as I said before the ajax call, he replied that the Token not available

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER', null, 'Unable to access this page!');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $this->getUser();

        if ($entity->getId() != $id) {
            $response = new JsonResponse(
            array(
                'message' => 'Não tem permissao'
            ), 400);

        return $response;
        }

        $form_update = $this->updateForm($entity);
        $form_update->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form_update->isValid()) {
            $entity->upload();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'Success!'), 200);
        }

        $response = new JsonResponse(
            array(
                'message' => $form_update->getErrors()
            ), 400);

        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: This literally makes no sense... sorry dude!

Comment: What does not make sense? If the question has badly formulated can edit.

Comment: is bundle_user__token supposed to have two underscores?

Comment: Yes, the nomenclature automatically generated by the form create is _user_ bundle <field name> then the padão name is <_token>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I notice that your click event for #upload_image fires a click trigger on #bundle_user_file, but below that you are asking it to look for a change event. Therefore, this would do nothing.

You can re-generate a CSRF token if you want by calling the csrf token_manager service by doing this:

```
/** @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrf */
$csrf = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager');
$token = $csrf->refreshToken($tokenId);

return new Response($token);
```

You can determine $tokenId in your form, if you want, or just use your picture ID, or whatever. Normally the CSRF token is generated automatically from your session, so you might want to check that too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function upload_img(){
        var file_data = $('.myform').find('.drawing').prop("files")[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();       
        form_data.append("drawing", file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  form_data,
            contentType: false,
            dataType:'json',
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {   
            },
              error: function() 
            {
            }             
       });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form class='myform'>
  <input type='file' class='drawing' onchange='upload_img()' >
</form>
```